# How to make unlimited number of fair coin be equivalent to two fair dice that takes the sum of their outcomes?

Tags: probability, algorithmic-randomness

I have an exercise in Randomized algorithm it takes me time to answer it but this king of question is new for me and I need a hint to begin with.

Problem 1.3 [Motwani and Raghavan's textbook] (Due to D.E. Knuth and A. C-C. Yao) Suppose you are provided with a source of unbiased random bits. Provide efficient (in terms of expected running time and expected number of random bits used) schemes for generating samples from the distribution over the set {2,3,4, ...,12} induced by rolling two unbiased dice and taking the sum of their outcomes.

In simple words, we need to make fair coin which produces an equivalent two fair dice that takes the sum of their outcomes. Also, we need to design an algorithm that does this job.

The problem that I have is I have 36 different possible of rolling two unbiased dice. But if you roll a coin you can have 32 or 64 possible values but you cannot have 36. So, there must be a way to make a re-step if we have a particular case. Another problem is that the first case where sum of dice equal 2 happens only once out of 36. Thus, suppose we have 6 digits, then 36x=64, x=1.76. Now how to simulate this 1.76 into discrete and do I need to round it up or down but if we round it up or down, then we do not have an exact simulation between 36 and 64.

I hope someone could answer this question or give me hint.

Thank you!

Comment: You could use $3$ bits for one die by e.g. excluding the outcomes 000 and 111. A rerun if one of these outcomes is achieved.

Comment: @drhab Ohh, Good idea! I did not think about it so you just make the 6 possible outcomes of dice be the 6 possible values of coin with three digits and eliminating 000 and 111. And if we have 000 or 111 we re-run again until we have other than these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the interval $[0,1[\>$ into half-open subintervals of length ${1\over36}$. Allocate the first of these subintervals to the sum (dice outcome) $2$, the next two to the sum $3$, the nect three to the sum $4$, and so on, until the last subinterval which is allocated to the sum $12$. In this way we have obtained a partition of $[0,1[\>$ into eleven *fractions*  whose lengths correspond to the probabilities of the various sums.

Now draw bits $b_k\in\{0,1\}$ from your random generator and observe the sums $$s_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n b_k 2^{-k}\qquad(n\geq1)\ .$$

**Stop** when $s_n+2^{-n}$ is in the same fraction as $s_n$.

The random variable $S$ representing the sum of two independent dice throws has entropy
$$H=\sum_{k=2}^{12} p_k \log_2\left({1\over p_k}\right)=3.2744\quad  {\rm [bits]}\ .$$
This means that in the "Shannon limit" $3.2744$ throws of a coin would be sufficient to simulate one sample of $S$. I made $3.6\cdot 10^6$ trials with the proposed algorithm, and came to $5.062$ drawings of a random bit per sample. This is better than the $6$ bits  required in other proposed setups.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The question asks for efficient algorithm. I just want to make sure, what is different between Expected running time and Expected number of random bits used? For me, expected running time is the Expected value of Algorithm so we need to analyse the algorithm to give expected running time, while Expected number of random bits is the number of bits we used to represent one dice. Is that correct!

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative algorithm that will run a little faster than others I've seen so far.
Generate random bits one at a time.
In the following, a string of binary digits is a sequence of random bits
in which the leftmost bit was generated first.
If you do not get six $1$s in the first six bits, continue to generate
bits until one of the sequences of bits on the left of an arrow below occurs;
then stop and  output the number on the right of the arrow.

\begin{array}{lll}
000 & \to & 5 \\
001 & \to & 6 \\
010 & \to & 7 \\
0110 & \to & 4 \\
0111 & \to & 5 \\
1000 & \to & 8 \\
1001 & \to & 9 \\
10100 & \to & 3 \\
10101 & \to & 5 \\
10110 & \to & 7 \\
10111 & \to & 9 \\
11000 & \to & 11 \\
110010 & \to & 2 \\
110011 & \to & 3 \\
110100 & \to & 4 \\
110101 & \to & 5 \\
110110 & \to & 9 \\
110111 & \to & 10 \\
111000 & \to & 11 \\
111001 & \to & 12 \\
1110100 & \to & 2 \\
1110101 & \to & 3 \\
1110110 & \to & 6 \\
1110111 & \to & 7 \\
1111000 & \to & 8 \\
1111001 & \to & 11 \\
1111010 & \to & 12 \\
11110110 & \to & 2 \\
11110111 & \to & 4 \\
11111000 & \to & 6 \\
11111001 & \to & 8 \\
11111010 & \to & 10 \\
11111011 & \to & 12 
\end{array}

If the first six bits are all $1$s, repeat the algorithm from the beginning.
This works because whenever the first six bits are not all $1,$ each of the outcomes from $2$ through $12$ is generated with $\frac{63}{64}$ of the probability it has of occurring as the sum of two fair dice.

The sequence of bits to generate a single outcome
consists of some number of repetitions of the sequence $111111,$
followed by one of the sequences in the table above.
The expected number of bits in the repetitions of $111111$ is 
$$
6 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{64^n} = \frac{128}{1323} \approx 0.0967498.
$$
The expected number of bits sequence after the last repetition of $111111$ is
$\frac{541}{128} \approx 4.2265625.$
The total is
$$
\frac{128}{1323} + \frac{541}{128} = \frac{732127}{169344} \approx 4.3233123.
$$